# Javascript toggle button to change its caption

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, toggle

The code i'm working with in HTML is as follows

```js
$(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    $("span.text").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Text ON</button>

<span class="text">Text</span>
```

When the button is clicked the text either appears or vanishes.

How do i make the button caption "Text ON" alternate with another caption "Text OFF" concurrently with appearance and disappearance of the text?

Comment: Have you tried $('button').value('Text ON') if the text is visible, and ....Text OFF if it's not? (Or vice versa, depending on what you want.)

Comment: Have you tried $('button').value('Text ON') if the text is visible, and ....Text OFF if it's not? (Or vice versa, depending on what you want.)

Comment: @mrunion no, i have not, i'm code illiterate, i'm asking to be shown the correct code verbatim

Comment: `i'm asking to be shown the correct code verbatim` that's not how this website works.

Comment: well i have nowhere else to ask

Comment: There are plenty of places that have tutorials for doing beginning website development using jQuery and such on the web. Lot's and lots of free tutorials, etc. We all start somewhere, but we must all make the effort. Good luck in your endeavors.

Comment: i'm not learning coding, i only need this one function, that's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `is(:visible)` method after toggling to check if the `span` is **visible** or **hidden**. Now based on the state, change the button text as below.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    var $btn = $(this);
    var $span = $("span.text");
    $span.toggle(400, function() {
      if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
        $btn.text('Text ON');
      } else {
        $btn.text('Text OFF');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Text ON</button>

<span class="text">Text</span>
```

Comment: is this possible to achieve without referencing jquery.min.js at all, provided i don't have to transfer the entire code into HTML?

Comment: That lib is pulled in this site to make the live code working.. You can stick with your way including the jquery. The main requirement here is the jQuery has to be present.

Comment: so basically i'll have to include the entire content of jquery.min.js, is that correct?

Comment: If jquery is not included in your site, then include it as you see in the above answer using a CDN link and script tag.